# How to normalize without excessive tables or columns?

Tags: mysql, permissions, attributes, relational-database, schema

I'm having trouble making the DB schema in MySQL for an attribute based permissions scheme.

I have three tiers of users in my application. Let's call them tiers 1, 2 and 3. At tier 1 I will have permission sets for tier 1, 2 and 3. At tier 2 I will have permission sets for tier 2 and 3. At tier 3, I will only have a permission set for tier 1.

There are some standard permissions which each tier use. However, each tier has at least one permission flag unique to only that tier. Furthermore, there are several permissions that are used by two tiers, but not the third.

My question is how to store this data. I can only come up with two ways and both seem wrong...

1) Have one table with every permission flag in every row.

(This seems like it would result in most rows having a bunch of unused columns, and also seems like it would be difficult to maintain because I have to remember which tier uses which permissions.)

2) Make SEVEN tables. One table for the base permissions, one table for each of the tiers and their specific permissions, and a table for every 2-tier combination.

(This seems like it's complete overkill and complicates the process of retrieving the permissions of a user by a lot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the current setup of permissions and tiers -- maybe that will change.

What you generally want is that if things change, you adapt by updating, deleting, inserting rows, not schema changes.  So, (1) doesn't allow new permissions (2) totally depends on which perms are in which tiers.

Keeping it general, tiers have multiple permissions, permissions can be in multiple tiers:

```
Tiers: id, name
Permissions: id, name
AllowedPermissions: id, tierId, permId // one row per allowed combo
```

If you want to model tier inheritance, you could add a `parentTierId` to Tiers or something like that.  You could also add an `inheritable` column to `Permissions` if some permissions are not inherited (because you said: "each tier has at least one permission flag unique to only that tier.")

Comment: Ahh, so I would simply store userId, tier, and permission in a row. Each user would have as many rows as they had permissions. Do need to define available permissions in the DB, then, or can I just define them in my model?

Comment: If you want to control the app behavior from db rows, you need to store the available permissions in the db and have the app read them.